# Deleting and Replacing a file in shell command

Tags: shell, sh

I'm trying to replace a file once the OMC is set. 
This code sets my "OMC" to the specific country code
Once this is done, I want to copy an xml file from a specific directory (this is just a random xml file I've edited with different parameters) and replace the original file in the OMC directory once the following script has detected the OMC.

In other words, to use an example, following this code I need to replace a file I have, let's just say, "temp/test.xml" to the directory "ABC/test.xml".
The "ABC/" directory will be the one the following the country code selected below.

```
getprop ro.boot.bootloader >> /tmp/BLmodel
ACTUAL_CSC=`cat /efs/imei/mps_code.dat`
ACTUAL_OMC=`cat /efs/imei/omcnw_code.dat`
SALES_CODE=`cat /system/omc/sales_code.dat`
sed -i -- "s/CSC=//g" /tmp/aroma/csc.prop
NEW_CSC=`cat /tmp/aroma/csc.prop`
buildprop=/system/build.prop
```

Comment: What have you ever tried?

Comment: I am not sure how to write to the directory the script has identified. I have tried the following but it's not writing or deleting the correct file. rm -r /temp1/test.xml
cp -r /temp2/test.xml /temp1/test.xml